# Hide the menu bar in Yosemite

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Is it possible to completely hide the menu bar on an external monitor? I'm using my laptop with a projector, and while I can set the desktop background to completely black, the menu bar is still there. Even in dark mode there is still text. I would like to avoid showing any desktop UI if the presentation (Keynote) exits.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possibly 'Displays have separate Spaces' in System Prefs > Mission Control.
I've had that switched off since it was added to prefs, & only have a menu bar on my main monitor.

<sup>I don't want to switch it back to test, it messes things up ;-)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Turn it on to see you have the correct answer, then turn it back off. You won't mess anything up. ;-)

Comment: @IconDaemon I have so many pre-designed Spaces in use, I don't dare ;)

Comment: I don't want the wrath of @Tetsujin on my head if it **does** mess up. Well played.